# Infinite time taken by scipy hypergeom function for some particular values

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I am using the `hypergeom` function from `scipy.stats`. Although it works for most of the parameter, it do not yeild anything for some particular parameters. For eg. the following works,

```
from scipy import stats

stats.hypergeom.interval(.94, 187601, 43192, 757)
(153.0, 196.0)

stats.hypergeom.interval(.93, 187601, 43192, 757)
(154.0, 195.0)

stats.hypergeom.interval(.96, 187601, 43192, 757)
(151.0, 198.0)
```

However changing the parameter to .95 do not yield any answer.

```
stats.hypergeom.interval(.95, 187601, 43192, 757)
```

Am I missing something or is it a bug in `scipy`?

Comment: looks like a bug to me that shows up only in some cases, https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/394

Comment: It seems that the fix has some additional problem. For e.g., `stats.hypergeom.ppf(0.02, 32335, 32335, 895)` no longer works.